# How to store a BitmapImage Localy or Roaming?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a class defining a Person. In the class I have it defined like this:

```
    [XmlIgnore]
    public BitmapImage PhotoSource
        {
        get { return _PhotoSource; }
        set
            {
            _PhotoSource = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged( "PhotoSource" );
            }
        }
```

I added the :

```
      [XmlIgnore]
```

vs. using the

```
      [DataMember]
```

since the serialization will not work with BitmapImage.

However, I still need to save the BitmapImage Local and/or Roaming.

How can that be accomplished?

Thanks,
 EitanB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file from your BitmapImage and then use the StorageFile class to write it to the filesystem.

```
    Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(bmImage.UriSource);
    await file.CopyAsync(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
```

To load the file back into a BitmapImage:

```
BitmapImage bmImage;
bmImage = new BitmapImage();

bmImage.UriSource = new Uri(new Uri(
     Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "\\" +
     Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Name), 
     "favicon.scale-100.ico");
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your answer.

How would I then re-load the same file from the LocalFolder into my BitmapImage?

Comment: I actually blogged about that here: http://windows8applicationdevelopment.blogspot.com/2012/09/loading-resources.html  See above for the snippet.